# R: generate possible permutation tables by one column

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I have a table that looks like this:

```
 Indikaatori nimi Alamkriteerium Kriteerium Skoor
1  Indikaator    1            1.1          1   100
2  Indikaator    2            1.2          1   100
3  Indikaator    3            1.3          1   100
4  Indikaator    4            1.1          1     0
5  Indikaator    5            2.1          2     0
6  Indikaator    6            2.1          2     0
... and so on...
```

I need to create all possible permutations of the table by the first column. 
There's a total of 50 indicators, from which i want to pick 49 and get all the possible combinations along with the chosen elements other data columns. 
With 49 elements out of 50, i will get a total of 50 permutations, but i want to automatically create all these tables without doing it manually (later on 48 elements is also necessary).

Is there any way to generate these 50 tables automatically with the respective data to the chosen elements?

All help and pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Do not confuse permutations with combinations.  Combinations are distinct subsets.  Permutations are distinct orderings.  What you want is combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# The following will give you a list of fifty data frames,
# Each data frame has a 49 row subset of the original
listoftables <- apply(combn(1:50, 49), 2, FUN = function(x) df[x,])
```

Comment: Is there a way i can append to a certain table? This indeed gives me the necessary tables, but now i'd also like to separate them to individual tables, which i want to process individually.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: something like this?   thisdf <- listoftables[[1]]

Comment: Note you can change the "49" above to a "48" and get back the 1225 subset data frames (48 rows each) that you said you would need later on.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses loops, which are rather slow compared to vectorized operations in R, but it will get you what you need in the form of a list of data.frames.

```
datatable = read.table(textConnection(
  "2  Indikaator    2            1.2          1   100
3  Indikaator    3            1.3          1   100
4  Indikaator    4            1.1          1     0
5  Indikaator    5            2.1          2     0
6  Indikaator    6            2.1          2     0"))


x = rep(list(data.frame(NULL)),times = 2^nrow(datatable))
a = 1
for (i in 1:nrow(datatable)){
  sets = combn(nrow(datatable),i)
  for (j in 1:ncol(sets)){
    x[[a]] = datatable[sets[,j],]
    a = a+1
  }
}
View(x[[10]])
```